# Line breaks are not displayed in the description of the application Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone, marketplace

I have a problem. I wrote a description of the application in the field "Description" with line breaks, but the store on windows phone 8.1 displays the description without line breaks. Please help, how to solve this problem?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqhnM.jpg)

Comment: I think that is by design

Comment: No, in other apps description view wiht line breaks